# How to solve the SDE $dB_t = r_tB_tdt$ when $r_t$ is stochastic?

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Suppose we have

$$dB_t = r_tB_tdt$$
and we have further that $r_t$ is a deterministic function of time $t$.
I know that this is simply an ODE with separable variables that has standard solution in $[t,T]$:
$$B_T = B_te^{\int_{t}^{T}r_sds} $$

but what if $r_t$ is stochastic? For example it could be

$$dr_t = \mu r_tdt + \sigma r_tdW_t$$

where $W_t$ is the Brownian motion.

Then $B_t$ itself is stochastic and how can I integrate something like

$$\int_{t}^{T}\frac{dB_t}{B_t}$$
Isn't this a stochastic integral? I am having hard times figuring out why in this case the solution is the same as when $r_t$ is deterministic.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Consider $ln B_t$ and apply Ito's. Then you have a solution of $B_t$ in terms of $r_t$, even $r_t$ is stochastic. The solution itself is just a random variable.

Comment: Ok I did it and that works!!! thank you!!! So the correct way to approach it is indeed using Ito.  Is there an intuition for the fact that the solution in this case is the same as the one of a ODE, despite being a SDE? maybe something related to the fact that the Brownian motion does not appear explicitly? anyway thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is still not a stochastic differential equation, since it does not have any stochastic part like

$$\mathrm{d} B_t=r_t B_t \, \mathrm{d}t+v_t B_t \, \mathrm{d} W_t.$$

Use the Itô-formula on $f(B_t)=\ln(B_t)$ to derive the following formula

$$\displaystyle \ln(B_t)=\ln(B_0)+\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{B_s}\, \mathrm{d}B_s+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_{0}^{t} -\frac{1}{B^2_s} \, \mathrm{d}\langle B \rangle_s.$$

Where $\langle B \rangle$ is the quadratic variation of $B$ which satisfies $\mathrm{d}\langle B \rangle_t=v^2_t B^2_t \, \mathrm{d}t$.
Substituate this to the above formula.

$$\displaystyle \ln(B_t)=\ln(B_0)+\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{B_s}\, \mathrm{d}B_s-\frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_{0}^{t} v^2_s \, \mathrm{d}s.$$

From here it is quite obvious, that

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{B_s}\, \mathrm{d}B_s=\ln(B_t)-\ln(B_0)+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_{0}^{t} v^2_s \, \mathrm{d}s.$$

In your case $v_t=0$ and that is the reason why you have observed that the solution of your equation matches with the solution of the ODE, since it does not have any part of stochastic integration only Lebesgue integration applied to a stochastic variable, but there is not any integral which includes stochastic integrator process. You can substitute now $\mathrm{d} B_t=r_t B_t \, \mathrm{d}t$

$$\displaystyle \ln(B_t)-\ln(B_0)+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_{0}^{t} v^2_s \, \mathrm{d}s=\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{B_s}\, \mathrm{d}B_s=
\int_{0}^{t} r_s\, \mathrm{d}s.$$

$$\displaystyle \ln(B_t)=\ln(B_0)+\int_{0}^{t} r_s\, \mathrm{d}s-\frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_{0}^{t} v^2_s \, \mathrm{d}s.$$

$$B_t=B_0\cdot \mathrm{e}^{\ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{t}r_s \, \mathrm{d}s -\frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_{0}^{t} v^2_s \, \mathrm{d}s}$$

If one assumes that $v_t=0$ that leads to the above mentioned formula you had.

$$B_t=B_0\cdot \mathrm{e}^{\ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{t}r_s \, \mathrm{d}s}.$$

Comment: what I don't understand is when you say that "it does not have any part of stochastic integration only Lebesgue integration applied to a stochastic variable, but there is not any integral which includes stochastic integrator process". That part is not clear to me ... why is it not a stochastic integral even if we are integrating with respect to a stochastic process $B_t$? Thank you anyway I up-voted you

Comment: Since $B_t$ does not contain any $\mathrm{d}W_t$ part. It has a bounded variation which means another stochastic (or deterministic) process can by integrated by it in the Lebesgue-Stieltjes sense of way. It clearly is a stochastic process but it has a quadratic variation of 0.

Comment: but it contains $dW_t$ through $r_t$ doesn't that count?

Comment: $\mathrm{d}B_t$ contains directly $r_t$, but it does not contains $\mathrm{d}r_t$ it is not the same.

Comment: thank you for the answer ..it is still not clear to me how can you say that $B_t$ is well behaved despite being a function of $W_t$ through $r_t$ .. could you give me some reference so that I can look into it more in depth?